# Computing covariance of pricing errors in r

Tags: r, matrix, covariance

I am trying to compute the covariance matrix of pricing errors as an input to the **Fama-MacBeth joint test statistic** given here.
I am not sure whether i am doing this correctly and was hoping for some help.

I was gonna post some pictures of those formulas,but i need at least 10 reputation points to post images...so i am gonna use imageur

[here](http://imgur.com/WG6zTL3) is the joint test i am trying to compute :

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD5Be.jpg) is the covariance formula:

My code is as follows

```
alpha.diff1 <- full.resid-full.mean.resid
alpha.diff2 <- t(alpha.diff1)
alpha.sum <- alpha.diff1%*%alpha.diff2
cov.term <- alpha.sum/(full.num.t^2)

full.joint.test <- t(full.mean.resid)%*%ginv(cov.term)%*%full.mean.resid
```

the variable names are pretty self explanatory i think.

- **full.num.t** : T in the formulas (total monthly observations)
- **full.resid** : Stores the alpha(it) [25 rows of assets,192 columns of monthly errors

the result for the **full.joint.test** variable is **20.86672**

Can someone confirm whether i have done this correctly please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question doesn't really fit the site, since it essentially is about proofreading your code rather than answering a specific programming problem.

Comment: Any help would still be appreciated...

Comment: Wrap the calculation into a function, create some data where you can determine the expected result (maybe with pen & paper) and use a unit testing package to see if your function gives the right answer.

Comment: I would have guessed that the `alpha_i` and `alpha_j` terms were row and column means, but you are the one with the textbook.

Comment: DWin,there seem to be different versions of this formula for some reason..i would imagine it comes down to notation really.Most websites,pdfs have it as i only no js